# How many lines of code are in this file?

Tags: bash, wc

I'm trying to figure out how many lines of code I have for files that end in *.pp

```
 find . -name *.pp -type f  | wc -l
  39
```

I know that I have 39 files, how can I figure out how many lines of code those 39 files contain?

Answer (score 4):

Try this version:

```
$ find . -iname "*.pp" -type f  -exec wc -l {} +
```

Here's an example using `.cpp` files:

```
$ find . -iname "*.cpp" -type f -exec wc -l {} +
  229 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/utilsfuncswin.cpp
  269 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/utilsfuncs.cpp
   84 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/jrubyexe.cpp
   85 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/unixlauncher.cpp
  250 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/platformlauncher.cpp
  593 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/argparser.cpp
  452 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/jvmlauncher.cpp
   77 ./jruby-launcher-1.0.7-java/jruby.cpp
 2039 total
```

I believe if you have more files than will fit on a single command line call to `wc` that it will give you a total per each call, but this can be modified to do a total of totals if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The following will do the job

```
find . -name *.pp -type f -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using the `wc` command on its own?!
`wc -l *.pp` would yield the expected result (if all the files are in the same folder, although you could expand on it by doing `wc -l FolderA/*.pp FolderB/*.pp`)
And if you are only after the grandtotal, without individual file results:
`find . -name "*.pp" -type f -exec cat {} + | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

@spuder attempted to use [`wc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) in this command to count "*.pp" files:

```
find . -name *.pp -type f  | wc -l
```

There are a few problems:

- the glob expression should be quoted so that is passed to `wc`
- `wc` does not open the filenames passed as input and count *those*
- `wc` is counting total lines in the file.

OP did not explain what the files were. There are a few possibilities, most more obscure than what appears in OP's [profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/39263/spuder?tab=profile).
Given that profile, the ".pp" suffix refers to Puppet files, which are essentially a metadata declaration in Ruby syntax.  Those files can have [comments](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.4/reference/lang_comments.html) (beginning with `#`) and blank lines.

The usual interpretation of *lines of code* ignores those.  Whether you want *physical* lines of code (total *lines* ignoring comments and blank lines) or *source* lines of code (the number of *statements*) depends on how picky you want to be.

Puppet's syntax is more complicated than that (it also allows C-style comments and has quoted strings), but for the sake of example, here is a very simple filter that trims out `#` comments and blank lines (using the `examples` directory of Puppet 2.7.10)

```
find . -type f -name "*.pp" -exec sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*#/d' -e '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' {} + |wc -l
 429
```

in contrast to unfiltered:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pp" -exec cat {} + |wc -l
477
```

Further reading:

- [Puppet 4.4 Reference Manual](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/)
- [A SLOC Counting Standard](http://csse.usc.edu/TECHRPTS/2007/usc-csse-2007-737/usc-csse-2007-737.pdf)  (Nguyen, Deeds-Rubin, Tan, Boehm)
- [Differences in the Definition and Calculation
  of the LOC Metric in Free Tools](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~beszedes/research/SED-TR2014-001-LOC.pdf) (Siket, Beszédes, Taylor)